# Why is ARKit with SceneKit SCNNode orientation not changing?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

In my app, I am using ML to detect objects, then add a simple shape on top of them. When the correct object is detected, I call a function as follows

```
func addDot(bBox: CGRect) {
        // Convert point to the right coordinates
        let midPoint = CGPoint(x: viewportSize.width * bBox.midX,
                               y: viewportSize.height - (viewportSize.height * bBox.midY))
        
        guard let arHitTestResult = sceneView.hitTest(midPoint, types: [.featurePoint]).first else {return}

        
        let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: arHitTestResult.worldTransform)
        sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
    }
```

The added anchor is handled in the renderer

```
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        if anchor is ARPlaneAnchor {
            // node for plane anchor
            let anchorNode = SCNNode()
            return anchorNode
        } else {
            // must be node for most recent hit test
            let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNCylinder(radius: dotSize, height: 0.05))
            node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
            node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
            node.simdOrientation = simd_quatf(angle: Float.pi/2.0, axis: SIMD3<Float>(0.0, 1.0, 0.0))
            return node
        }
    }
```

Without the call to `simdOrientation`, the cylinder was vertical. I wanted it to be horizontal, so it would look like a small dot (on a vertical wall).

Unfortunately, the `simdOrientation` does not seem to do anything. How do I get the SCNCylinder to rotate like I would like?

Comment: Try using an intermediate node -  [How do I rotate a SCNNode in "func renderer(SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704401/how-do-i-rotate-a-scnnode-in-func-rendererscnscenerenderer-nodefor-aranchor)

Comment: @JamesP, thanks for pointing me to that. It works just fine.